# Which record is causing the error in the Merge Command in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

```
DECLARE @SummaryOfChanges TABLE (Change VARCHAR(20)); 

MERGE Target T
USING Source S ON (S.id = T.id)

WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET T.customerID = S.customerID
   -- Code to update the target table

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT  -- code to insert

OUTPUT $action INTO @SummaryOfChanges;
```

Few records are giving exception if the data is not correct for the customer ID. Issue is of the length of the S.customerId. I want to know for which S.Id or T.Id the issue has occurred. I don't want to handle the exception but want to know which record has caused the exception.

There are many columns which has to be updated. I have added one column for reference. There are approx. 93 columns and each column can give exception for one reason or other. So want to know the record which has caused the exception then will fix the table.

Comment: Select rows from `Source` where `customerID` does not match the requirements.

Comment: There are many columns which has to be updated. I have added one column for reference. There are approx. 93 columns and each column can give exception for one reason or other. So want to know the record which has caused the exception them will fix the table

Comment: 90+ columns might be a sign of a poor database design... You should consider refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't work like that, all operations are set based. If one element fails then the whole query fails.

You can use a tool like SSIS which can handle this, or use a cursor to do RBAR (which will be slow) or as suggested by the comments, write a query to identify rows which are going to fail.